# ajax error callback is called before firing the action in Symfony 2

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm trying to write an application with Symfony and I'm new to it. I have an ajax call in this application. The problem is that it always fires error call back . I put breakpoint in netbeans IDE and can see that error callback is fired before firing the specified action in the url property of ajax.

action code:

```
public function userNameExistsAction()
{
    return 'success';
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#register_submit').click(function(){
    var path = '/symfony/web/app_dev.php/account/userNameExists';
    //var userName = $('#register_userName').val();        
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'GET',                        
        success: function(){ alert('success');},
        error: function() {              
          console.log('error');
        }
    });        
});
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if this script resides in your `.twig` file try replacing:

```
var path = '/symfony/web/app_dev.php/account/userNameExists';
```

with

```
var path = '{{ path('route_of_userNameExists') }}';
```

---

### UPDATE

If path is actually correct, I assume you wanted to do this:

```
return new Response("success");
```

You can return instance of `array` (for templating) or `Response` object.

Comment: Ah, OK then. Have you tried returning `Response` object instead (as in updated answer)?

Comment: Well, the best way to see what went wrong is by looking up the log file (app/logs directory). Also install `Firebug` which will help you debug the request...

Comment: I added e.preventDefault(); before ajax call and it worked. And I have to use Response. But the question is that I want to use e.preventDefault(); when the ajax is seccessfull.